# Send Curl POST with string

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a Curl request to an EndPoint. This request has a param which a string text. The function at the Endpoint only return the same string. The issue is that the Endpoint's function only return the first word of the String.

Here is the code I use:

```
$params = $_SESSION['search'].'/'.$_SESSION['page'];
$curl   = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => 'Stlfinder',
    CURLOPT_POST            => false,
    CURLOPT_URL             => "mydomain.com/api/search/$params"
));
$resultados = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$resultados   = json_decode($resultados);
print_r($resultados);
```

This is what I get:

```
stdClass Object ( [result] => The )
```

and the String sent is: 'The mansion book'

Is there anything missing in the Curl?

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `$params`?

Comment: I also notice that your question is about POST, but you have POST set to false and the string contains spaces but is not urlencoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your query string has spaces, it's getting chopped off at the first space. I think you need something like:

```
$params = rawurlencode($_SESSION['search'].'/'.$_SESSION['page']);
```

That will replace the spaces with %20 and will handle other non-alpha characters in other strings.

Comment: Well, I used your function and at the first time did not work. I made a little changes. $params = rawurlencode($_SESSION['search']).'/'.$_SESSION['page'];

Comment: Great. Glad it helped.